# Calculate $Ea^{\tau}$ where $\tau=\inf\space[{n: X_1+...+X_n=1}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Calculate $Ea^{\tau}$ for any $a\in (0,1)$ where $\tau=\inf\space[{n: X_1+...+X_n=1}]$ $X_i$ are independent and have distrbution as such: $P(X_i=-1)=P(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}$ I will add that the first part of the excercise was to find the conditions for a and b such as $Y_n=a^nb^{X_1+...+X_n}$ be a submartingale, the result which I acquired is $ab^2-2b+1>=0$ Thanks for any help, I have litteraly any idea on how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $a=\left(\frac{b+b^{-1}}2\right)^{-1}$ for $b>1$, then we can observe that
$$
M_n=a^n b^{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}, \quad n\ge 0
$$ is a martingale from $\Bbb E[M_n|M_{n-1}]=aE[b^{X_n}]M_{n-1}=M_{n-1}$. From this, one can notice that the stopped process
$$
M_{n\wedge \tau}=M_\tau 1_{\tau \le n} +M_n1_{\tau> n}
$$ is also a non-negative, bounded martingale. By optional sampling theorem, we obtain
$$
1=\Bbb E[M_{\tau\wedge n}]=\Bbb E[a^\tau b1_{\{\tau \le n\}}]+\Bbb E[M_n1_{\tau> n}].
$$ The second term tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, since on $\{\tau>n\}$,
$$
0\le M_n \le a^n b\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0,
$$ and by Lebesgue's dominated convergence therorem. This gives for all $a\in (0,1)$,
$$
\Bbb E[a^\tau 1_{\{\tau<\infty\}}]=\frac1{b}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}.
$$ By letting $a\to 1^-$, we get $\Bbb P(\tau <\infty) = 1$, and finally
$$
\Bbb E[a^\tau ]=\frac1{b}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, the last thing I do not understand is why we can use the optional sampling theorem, as n is not bounded and only later on we discover that $\tau$ is almost surely not inifinity.

Comment: @ryszardeggink For each $n\ge 1$, $\tau\wedge n$ is a bounded stopping time. Hence $\Bbb E[M_{\tau\wedge n}] =\Bbb E[M_0]=1$ for each and every $n\ge 1$. Does this make it clear now?

Comment: But how is it bounded?  Is n not arbitrary?

Comment: @ryszardeggink It is bounded for each **fixed** $n\ge 1$. But $\tau \wedge n$, $\ n\ge 1$ is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: I am still confused, as we later on go with n to infinity, but in order to use the theorem we fixed it...

Comment: @ryszardeggink Umm ... we can take limit $n\to\infty$ as long as $$\Bbb E[M_{\tau\wedge n}] = 1,\quad \forall n\ge 1$$ is true ...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer once again ! it seems more clear to me now.